# Automate the boring stuff with python - Comma Code

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, strings

> ## Comma Code
>
> Say you have a list value like this:
>
> ```
> spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
> ```
>
> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a
> string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with `and`
> inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam
> list to the function would return `'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'`.
> But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to
> it.

```
# Function for getting user input.
def get_input():
    user_input = input('Enter some random stuff: ')
    return user_input

# Function for appending the input to the list
def logic_code(input, big_list):
    big_list.append(input)
    return big_list
    
# Function for printing the output
def print_output(big_list):
    while True:
        input = get_input()
        if input == 'Done': # If user input == 'Done', break loop.
            break
        logic_output = logic_code(input, big_list) # Output of logic_code
    output = print(logic_output)
    return output

def main() -> None:
    big_list = []
    print('Type Done to stop.')
    output = print_output(big_list)
    


if __name__ == '__main__': # Program starts here, then main() get's called.
    main()
```

This was a 'simple' exercise; I had to think a bit more with everything being a function, bit it looks a lot neater.

Everything is in functions; could I have handle the user input differently?

Should int and floats be in a separate list?

Comment: This is very much not what the specification asked for. It doesn't require user input, and it does require the word `and`

Comment: @Reinderien Dam my bad looks like i went to quickly, but i thought this meant user input = But your function should be able to work with any list value **passed** to it.

Comment: Are you sure about the comma before "and"? Does not look quite right to me...

Comment: @slepic, that's known as an [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) (also as Serial, or Harvard, comma), and the example in the spec shows it clearly is required here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement asks for

> a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string

That's not what we have here.  This requirement means our function should have the following form:

```
def join_strings(items: list[str]) -> str:
    '''
    Combine the members of "items" into a single string,
    with commas between each item, and 'and' before the last.
    '''
```

I've used type annotations to be completely clear about the inputs and outputs.  Even if you've not seen these before, I think you should be able to see how they describe this function.

We can test it manually like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(join_strings(ham', 'eggs', 'sausage', 'spam']))
```

Or we can use [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) to embed some automated testing as examples in our documentation string:

```
def join_strings(items: list[str]) -> str:
    '''
    Combine the members of "items" into a single string,
    with commas between each item, and 'and' before the last.

    For example:

    >>> join_strings(['Dave Dee', 'Dozy', 'Beaky', 'Mick', 'Tich'])
    'Dave Dee, Dozy, Beaky, Mick, and Tich'

    >>> join_strings(['ham', 'eggs', 'sausage', 'spam'])
    'ham, eggs, sausage, and spam'

    >>> join_strings(['fish', 'chips'])
    'fish, and chips'

    >>> join_strings(['soup'])
    'soup'
    '''
```

We exercise these tests by adding a couple of lines (don't worry if this looks like magic - for now, just consider it the standard incantation for self-tested code):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

With that framework in place, I encourage you to re-write the logic so that matches the requirements.

Comment: I posted a new version as a new question or should i have just edited this one?

Also could you explain this: **def join_strings(items: list[str]) -> str:**

for what reason do you use **items: list[str]**, is that part of the type annotation?

Thank you for the reply's it is very helpful to get feedback from outside!

Comment: Yes, that says that the `items` argument is a list of strings, and the result of the function is a single string.

Comment: And yes, a new question is the right thing to do - don't change code in a question when it has been answered.  Full explanation in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body)

Answer (score 2):

Not all edge cases are handled. Separating the main logic and user input was a good idea, but you should contain all aspects of the said function. For example, everything related to the input is inside `get_input()`. It should just return all the words in a list. Everything related to the logic should go to the logic_function. Which is you are adding words with a comma and a space and adding a `and` before the last word. Here is an example:

```
# Function for getting user input.
def get_input():
    print("Type Done to stop.")
    words = []
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter words: ")
        if user_input.lower() == "done":
            return words
        words.append(user_input)

# The logic
def concatenate_words(words: list):
    if len(words) > 1:
        words[-1] = "and " + words[-1]
    sentence = ", ".join(words)
    return sentence

def print_output():
    words = get_input()
    sentence = concatenate_words(words)
    print(sentence)

def main():
    print_output()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Again, not all edge cases are handled, and there are other ways to do it, but keep things simple, readable, and testable is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need that much code to turn the list into a sentence:

```py
def sentencefromlist(listinput):
 l = list(listinput) # Assigns the list form of the argument to the variable 'l'.
 l[-1] = 'and ' + l[-1] # Prepends the string 'and ' to the last item in the list.
 return ', '.join(l) # Returns the whole list concatenated together as a string, with each item split by ', '.
```

Now for the function that collects user input:

```py
def getinput():
 l=[] # Initialise an empty list.
 while True: # Repeats forever, or until the programme encounters a break statement.
  i=input("Please enter the next item, or 'Done' if you have entered all the items: ") # Gets user input for the next item.
  if i == "Done": # Checks if the input was 'Done'.
   break # Breaks out of the loop if the input was 'Done'.
  l.append(i) # Appends the input. Will not be reached if the break statement was activated.
 return l # Returns the list with the user input.
```

With this, `main()` is simply a function chain, so we can pack it into a `lambda` easily:

```py
main=lambda:print(sentencefromlist(getinput())) # Defines the variable 'main' as a lambda function the prints the return value of the 'sentencefromlist' function when given the argument 'getinput()'.
if __name__ == '__main__': # Checks if this is the main script
 main() # Runs the lambda function in the variable 'main' if this is the main script.
```

The full code:

```py
def sentencefromlist(listinput):
 l = list(listinput) # Assigns the list form of the argument to the variable 'l'.
 l[-1] = 'and ' + l[-1] # Prepends the string 'and ' to the last item in the list.
 return ', '.join(l) # Returns the whole list concatenated together as a string, with each item split by ', '.

def getinput():
 l=[] # Initialise an empty list.
 while True: # Repeats forever, or until the programme encounters a break statement.
  i=input("Please enter the next item, or 'Done' if you have entered all the items: ") # Gets user input for the next item.
  if i == "Done": # Checks if the input was 'Done'.
   break # Breaks out of the loop if the input was 'Done'.
  l.append(i) # Appends the input. Will not be reached if the break statement was activated.
 return l # Returns the list with the user input.

main=lambda:print(sentencefromlist(getinput())) # Defines the variable 'main' as a lambda function the prints the return value of the 'sentencefromlist' function when given the argument 'getinput()'.
if __name__ == '__main__': # Checks if this is the main script
 main() # Runs the lambda function in the variable 'main' if this is the main script.
```